# How do I format an hour string to local time in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is probably a duplicate but I'm stuck, and cannot find such a specific reference...

I can get the local time in this method:

```
NSLog(@"incoming date  : %@", etdString);
NSDateFormatter *incomingFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[incomingFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *incomingDate = [incomingFormat dateFromString: etdString];
NSLog(@"incoming formatted date  : %@", incomingDate);
```

This produces the date string correctly showing the local time.

Now, I need the hour component.

I used this clip:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:incomingDate];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", hour];
```

But my problem is that `hourString` shows UTC time. I need the local time here too.

Any advice is welcome.

UPDATE: This is my log output from the current code:

`[StopScheduleController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] incoming date  : 2015-05-21T05:50:00
incoming formatted date  : 2015-05-21 09:50:00 +0000
incoming formatted hourString  : 5`

Please note the hours in the first two lines.

Comment: What you claim is "local time" above should not be local time, but rather UTC, since you are dumping an NSDate object without formatting.

Comment: ok. I don't claim anything, and perhaps I'm wrong, but I've added some logs to my question.

Comment: What you're dumping is as expected.  The incoming date is assumed to be local time and converted to UTC.  Then `hourString` shows the hour in local time.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: You don't have a problem, that I can see.  If the incoming date string is local time your code above should work just fine.  If it's not local time (but is instead UTC) you need to fix that, by, at a minimum, setting the timezone of the NSDateFormatter to UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the date formatter again:

```
[incomingFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString * timeString = [incomingFormat stringFromDate:incomingDate];
```

`NSDateFormatter` uses the current locale, which includes the current time zone, [by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

Or, perhaps even more simply, use the class method [`+localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:):

```
NSString * timeString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:incomingDate
                                                       dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                                       timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm working with your code now. I appreciate the help.